# using join and push result in the array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables , Names and Pics

Names table :

[image]

Pics table :

[image]

I would like to write a function in the php(by using sql) that it gets an id and return a result like this :

//suppose I sent 1 to this function...

> result = array("name"=>"Name1","pics"=>"url6-url7");

There are hyphen in the URLS.

any helps?

Comment: what have u tried so far ?

Comment: I just know : $sql = "select * from Names,Pics where Names.ID = Pics.Name_ID";

Comment: `select * from Names,Pics where Names.ID = Pics.Name_ID AND Names.ID=$inputId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function whatIsThis($id){
   global $db;
   $sql = "select name, pics from names,pics where names.ID = pics.Name_ID AND names.ID = ".$id;
   $res = $db->query($sql);
   // Logic starts here...
   foreach($res as $rk=>$rv){ 
      $result['name'] = $rv['name'];
      $r[] = $rv['pics'];
   }
   $result['pics'] = implode('-',$r);
   return $result;
}
$iWant = whatIsThis('1');
```

I've used my own database class for query, you can use your own..
`$iWant` will return array as you need!

Answer (score 2):

```
`Try this code its working 

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(category.pics SEPARATOR '-') as newpics, company.id as searchid FROM `category` inner join  company on (company.id = category.cmp_id) where category.cmp_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your sql result in $sql, use `var_dump` to print the result and you will get the output result in the form of array that you want :)